# What is 'gesture' and is it 'going' short form for 'is going'?'

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage

In [this drawing lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2T7cDY7YDsg) at around [13:16](https://youtu.be/2T7cDY7YDsg?t=796), the drawing teacher (artist) draws one line back and then the second line down and explain:

> [image]
>
> So gesture going back, gesture going down.

What is 'gesture' for him (direction? or movement? or direction of movement?)and why he say 'going' I mean why not 'is going' or 'goes'?

Comment: In the future, please include a source, such as a book title, a YouTube link, etc. with your posts. See [Why you should cite your source](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1084/36187).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like he's just omitting some of his sentence, meant to be a command.

*So, [perform a] gesture going back, [and] a gesture going down.*

This could really be interpreted in a few ways, but either way, the meanings are similar.

In this case, "going" is used like a preposition. He's using it to show the direction of the gesture from its starting point.

Comment: 'going - a preposition' it is beyond the mind of not native speaker.  Can you clarify what else can be like a preposition?